# Not Accessing Google Account from my Android phone

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am working on accessing to my google account from my android phone. My android phone has Android 6.0 Marshmallow and all sdk is installed(include google play services) and all permissions have granted. But the problem is that my phone is not accessing my google account. Here is my code, thanks for helps..

```
package com.example.kaya.billtech;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView name;
    TextView surname;
    Button button;
    TextView welcomeEmail;
    String email;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        surname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_surname);
        welcomeEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeEmail);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_register);
        String email = getUsername();
        welcomeEmail.setText("Welcome " + email);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
        Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        List<String> possibleEmails = new LinkedList<String>();

        for (Account account : accounts) {
            possibleEmails.add(account.name);
        }

        if (!possibleEmails.isEmpty() && possibleEmails.get(0) != null) {
            String email = possibleEmails.get(0);
            String[] parts = email.split("@");
            if (parts.length > 0 && parts[0] != null)
                return parts[0];
            else
                return null;
        } else
            return null;
    }
}
```

And here is my permissions;

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Marshmallow all dangerous permissions belong to permission groups.

You need to ask euntime permissions for devices with Marshmallow and above.
The permission `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` belongs to `CONTACTS` group

You can use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

For more information about permission and their groups here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: Thanks but "READ_CONTACTS" and "WRITE_CONTACTS" permissions added and it is not working again. Also ı added;
<permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.CONTACTS"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
        android:description="@string/app_name"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
still not workingg..

Comment: But the main thing here is adding runtime permission.You need to show dialog why you are asking permission and also user has to approve permission.Did you add that?

Comment: Do testing for now go to your app info page and inside permission column enable contacts and check if app works.

Comment: Also dont forget to add runtime permission in your code..see this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html